# Comma Missing When Converting From xls to csv

Tags: excel, csv, xls

I have an excel spreadsheet that has two columns.  When I choose to save it as a csv file, the comma after the second column is not in place.  For example, i get this:

```
Invoice,SID No.
156106,ELC204R8
156106,WXC2048V
```

Instead of this:

```
Invoice,SID No.,
156106,ELC204R8,
156106,WXC2048V,
```

How to I get the comma in right before the line break?

Comment: Why are you expecting a comma there?  That's not a normal csv format.

Comment: I was importing into a mysql database using sqlyog, and the import only works if there is a comma before the line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just entered a space into the first 20 rows and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This as I assume you are aware is not a usual requirement/format for saved CSV file.

To achieve what you are trying to do though, you need to trick Excel into thinking you are exporting a third blank/empty column.

One way to do this is to add the single-quote character `'` into a third Excel column before exporting.